# Evaluate the integral by interpreting it in terms of areas

Tags: calculus, geometry, definite-integrals, area

> Evaluate the integral by interpreting it in terms of areas. In other words, draw a picture of the region the integral represents, and find the area using high school geometry.
> $$
> \int_0^4 |5x−2|dx
> $$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried finding ∫|5x−2|dx, a=0,b=0.4 + ∫|5x−2|dx, a=0.4,b=4 i got 32.8 but it was wrong ( i got the 0.4 by 5x-2>=0)

Comment: Why don't you draw the plot as suggested and note the area you want is just 2 right triangles? [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BAbs%5B5x-2%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C4%7D%5D) is the suggestion from WolframAlpha

Comment: @RouaSabbagh I see you are new to SO, so just remember to put what you tried into your question. This way, people know that you made a good faith effort and will be happy to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So visually the absolute value means your function can be decomposed into two different lines over the region x: [0,4]. As you found the line changes direction at x = 0.4, as this is where |5x - 2| changes sign.

So if we let y = |5x - 2|, then at x = 0, y = 2; at x = 0.4, y = 0; at x = 4, y = 18. Draw a line between (0,2) and (0.4,0) and find the area over the region x:[0,0.4]. Then draw a line between (0,2) and (4,18), and find the area over this region.

[image]

Using the area for triangles, you should get $(1/2)(0.4)(2) + (1/2)(4-0.4)(18) = 32.8$

Answer (score 0):

Note that, $|5x-2|=0$ in $x=\frac{2}{5}$. Then 
$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{4}|5x-2|dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{2}{5}}(2-5x)dx+\int_{\frac{2}{5}}^{4}(5x-2)dx$